# Can I add custom menu item on a timelineitem from other service?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Can I add a custom menu item to a timelineitem of the system or another glassware app?

For example, "take a picture" adds a timeline item, which has two options, share or delete. Is there a way to add a custom menu option to this timeline item, share, delete, or "do something"?

Answer (score 3):

You can only access timeline items that have been created by or shared with your Glassware.

When a user shares the picture with one of your Glassware contacts you will get an exact copy of the card, which you can then manipulate with timeline.update or timeline.patch however you feel necessary, including adding/removing menu items. This won't affect the original "picture card" in the user's timeline, but only the copy that has been shared with your service.

You can add a feature request to the [Glass Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) explaining why and how you want to access those other cards.

Comment: You mean whenever user takes a picture, my glassware will be get notified? Is there a way to add a intent which kind of allow to extend the functionality of the data content of the timeline item.

Comment: No, whenever a user shares a picture with you, your glassware will get notified. This is a function of the "Share" menu option which is attached to pictures and video. This is very roughly equivalent to the intent, but is handled differently for consistency (you're leveraging the Share action, instead of trying to add your own actions).

Comment: Yes, I could use the share intent to share picture to my glassware app and i could process further.